# ForeignKey instance error Exception at Django

Tags: django

I get this error when I register the Personel form; "Exception Value: Cannot assign "5": "db_PERSONEL.db_departman" must be a "db_DEPARTMAN" instance. ".
Thanks.

departman_app.model.py

```
from django.db import models

class db_DEPARTMAN(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True, editable=False)
    db_departmanAdi = models.CharField(max_length = 50)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return u'%s' % (self.db_departmanAdi)
```

personel_app.models.py

```
from django.db import models
from departman.models import db_DEPARTMAN

class db_PERSONEL(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True, editable=False)
    db_personelAdi  = models.CharField(max_length = 50)
    db_departmanAdi = models.ForeignKey(db_DEPARTMAN, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING, related_name="tags")

    def __unicode__(self):
        return u'%s' % (self.db_departmanAdi)
```

personel_app.personelform.py

```
from django import forms
from personel.models import db_PERSONEL

class personelForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model=db_PERSONEL
        #fields="__all__"
        fields = [
            'db_personelAdi',
            'db_departmanAdi',
        ]

form = personelForm()
form.base_fields['db_personelAdi'] = forms.CharField(label='Personel Adı:', max_length=50,                                              widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}))

form.base_fields['db_departmanAdi'] = forms.IntegerField(label='Deaprtman Adı:', widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}))
```

Comment: Show the traceback.

Comment: The naming conventions here are painful... please check out [PEP 8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/?#naming-conventions) for some good guidelines to make your code more standard and readable.